# Send WM_COPYDATA Message Using System Windows Automation

Tags: c#, vb.net, winapi, automation

I am using following code to send a message/command to another window/process.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace AvroSwitch
{
    public class clsSwitch
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        public static extern Int32 FindWindow(String lpClassName, String lpWindowName);

        //For use with WM_COPYDATA and COPYDATASTRUCT
        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);

        public const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x4A;

        //Used for WM_COPYDATA for string messages
        public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
        {
            public IntPtr dwData;
            public int cbData;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string lpData;
        }

        private static int sendWindowsStringMessage(int hWnd, int wParam, string msg)
        {
            int result = -1;

            if (hWnd > 0)
            {
                byte[] sarr = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(msg);
                sarr = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, UnicodeEncoding.Unicode, sarr);
                int len = sarr.Length;
                COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
                cds.dwData = (IntPtr)0;
                cds.lpData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(sarr);
                cds.cbData = len + 1;
                result = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, ref cds);
            }

            return result;
        }

        private static int getWindowId(string className, string windowName)
        {
            return FindWindow(className, windowName);
        }

        public static int toBangla()
        {
            return sendWindowsStringMessage(getWindowId("TAvroMainForm1", null), 0, "bn");
        }

        public static int toEnglish()
        {
            return sendWindowsStringMessage(getWindowId("TAvroMainForm1", null), 0, "sys");
        }
    }
}
```

i am using 2 function toBangle() and to toEnglish(), but none of them is working.

but above code is not working. and i think this can be be easily achieved using system windows automaton.

**Update-1:**

this is the code from the third party app in delphi to send the exact command to main app/window.

```
Function SendCommand(cmd: String): boolean;
Var
     copyDataStruct           : TCopyDataStruct;
     receiverHandle           : THandle;
Begin
     result := false;
     copyDataStruct.dwData := 0;        //0=string
     copyDataStruct.cbData := 1 + Length(cmd);
     copyDataStruct.lpData := PChar(cmd);

     receiverHandle := FindWindow(PChar('TAvroMainForm1'), Nil);
     If receiverHandle = 0 Then
          Exit;


     SendMessage(receiverHandle, WM_COPYDATA, 0, Integer(@copyDataStruct));
     Result := True;
End;
```

**Update-2:**

And this is the code form main window/app, that process the wm command:

```
Procedure TAvroMainForm1.WMCopyData(Var Msg: TWMCopyData);
Var
         cmd: String;
Begin
         cmd := PChar(Msg.CopyDataStruct.lpData);
         cmd := Lowercase(cmd);

         If cmd = 'bn' Then Begin
                    KeyLayout.BanglaMode;
                    // Send something back
                    Msg.result := 21;
         End;

         If cmd = 'sys' Then Begin
                    KeyLayout.SysMode;

                    // Send something back
                    Msg.result := 21;
         End;
End;
```

any help would be highly appreciated..

Comment: Put `cds.dwData = (IntPtr)1;` Also show how the receiving app is processing `WM_COPYDATA`. Is the recipient expecting Unicode?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, sir, i don't know what the app expect and how it is work. as that is third party app. and the source is mentioned in post is also form the third party.

Comment: You say "the source is mentioned in post" but I don't see anything that says what the source is. Your conversion from string to bytes seems suspect. You convert the string to bytes via the Unicode encoding, so you now have bytes representing Unicode, but then you convert it from ASCII to Unicode, which doesn't make sense since the source is not in ASCII format. And then you decode that garbled chunk of bytes back to a string via Unicode.GetString. I would suggest using a debugger to make sure the values placed into the `cds` are what you expect.

Comment: *i don't know what the app expect and how it is work* You can't send `WM_COPYDATA` to any random app and expect a response. The third party app should give details about what it expects, if anything. By the way, I don't know what is *"System Windows Automation"*. Perhaps you should explain your goal. What message/command are you trying to send?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, sir, third party app is open source though is in delphi, but if i give you the link of that open source app, will that help sir?

Comment: Yes, you should show in the question where the third party program is responding `WM_COPYDATA`. Again, note that `WM_COPYDATA` has nothing to do with "automation"

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, sir, i have added delphi version of that code to send the same message to the main window/app. will that help you to understand better?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to pass ANSI text

```
string msg = "bn"; //or "sys"
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = (IntPtr)0;
cds.lpData = msg;
cds.cbData = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg).Length;
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_COPYDATA, wParam, ref cds);
```

This should work since `lpData` is already marshaled

> ```
> public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
> {
>     public IntPtr dwData;
>     public int cbData;
>     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
>     public string lpData;
> }
> ```

Comment: "that doesn't work" is a vague description of the problem. You are sending `"Text"`. The Delphi program is expecting to receive `"bn"` or `"sys"`. Put debug points in Delphi program to see how far it gets.

Comment: nope sir, i am not sending text, i send "bn" and "sys" both, but none of them seems to be working.. :(